# Github Actions Job being skipped

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Using Github Actions for some CI/CD.

Currently I am experiencing strange behavior where my jobs are being skipped despite the conditions being met. `deploy-api` has two conditions, if code was pushed to master and `test-api` was a success. But even though we are meeting those conditions, it is still being skipped.

```yaml
jobs:
  test-api:
    name: Run tests on API
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Get dependencies
        run: npm install
        working-directory: ./api
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm run test
        working-directory: ./api

  deploy-api:
    needs: test-api # other job must finish
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && needs.test-api.status == 'success' #only run if it's a commit to master AND previous success
```

[image]

As seen in the picture the second job is being skipped despite the push being on the master branch (as seen on the top) AND the previous job being successful.

Am I missing something in the code? Does anyone know of a workaround that can be used?

It would be nice if the UI told the user why it was skipped!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `needs.test-api.result == 'success'` (there is no `.status`) in the `if` expression.

See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#needs-context.

Answer (score 0):

Change `needs.test-api.status` to `needs.test-api.result`